# How to use native Equalizer in the App

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, audio-player, equalizer, android-music-player

I am using the following code to open the Equalizer in the App.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( );
intent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL");
if (intent.resolveActivity( getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null )
{
   startActivityForResult( intent , 100 );
}
else
{
   JBUtils.getInstance().showCustomToast( getActivity() , R.string.equalizer_notfound);
}
```

And added the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

After user changes the Equalizer settings how to apply equalizer settings in the currently playing audio file.We are using the Exoplayer for  playing the music file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this issue (closed):

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/252

There's an interesting example about using Equalizer in ExoPlayer.
I didn't try it yet but it seems an interesting starting point to integrate standard Equalizer in ExoPlayer.

Let me know if it works!

Here is the example I would start with:

```
audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(......){

private Equalizer equalizer;

@Override
public void onAudioSessionId ( int audioSessionId){
    releaseEqualizer();
    equalizer = new Equalizer(...,audioSessionId);
    // Configure equalizer here.
    equalizer.setEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled () {
    releaseEqualizer();
}

private void releaseEqualizer () {
    if (equalizer != null) {
        equalizer.release();
        equalizer = null;
    }
}
};
```

Moreover there seems to be some issue with the equalizer. You can try to enable the workaround (disabled by default) in AudioTrack, setting the following flag to true:

`public static boolean enablePreV21AudioSessionWorkaround = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the your package name and current Media Player audio session id as extra before starting the activity. Add the below code before calling startActivityForResult.

```
intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
intent.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, player.getAudioSessionId());
```

where player is an instance of MediaPlayer.